# Powershell can not connect Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to connect MS Graph API using PowerShell using below code :
Reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/authentication-commands?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

I am using "Using client secret credentials" method.

PS H:> $ClientSecretCredential = Get-Credential -Credential "applicationId"
PS H:> # Enter client_secret in the password prompt.
PS H:> Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "tenantId" -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential

I am receiving below error:

Connect-MgGraph : ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication -
check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration
portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client
secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for
a secret added to app '*******'. Trace ID: **********
Correlation ID: ************ Timestamp: 2024-03-20 12:15:41Z
At line:1 char:1

- Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "***********" -Cli ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-MgGraph], AuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Cmdlets.ConnectMgGraph
  ```

With same Client Id, Client Secret and Tenant Id, I can connect MS Graph API using C#.net without any issue.

How can I check the detail of error and resolve this ?

Comment: Powershell uses Net library so any c# connection should also work with Powershell.  Are you running PS from same machine as c#?  See if you are getting correct credentials in PS using  : $ClientSecretCredential | Format-List.

Comment: So, I am not trying to use C# connection in PowerShell.  Both programs are different. Yes,  I am using same machine to execute PowerShell where I can run .NET program. I can confirm that I m using same credential.

Comment: Did you check credentials like I said in PS?

Comment: You may also wish to add the `-ContextScope Process` parameter. Otherwise it could be attempting to login with your Windows credentials.

Comment: It was my bad. I had multiple application Ids and I was using wrong Application Id. Thanks jdweng and mike for your help. I can access MS Graph through PS now. I am closing this question.